# Flutter - App doesn't show any file pickers

Tags: flutter, filepicker

I've been facing this issue for a while.
My app has to pick a document from the storage, So I went with File [file_pciker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker), I've followed the exact documentations that the author has published with the plugin, And now he is not responding on the issues sections.
I've switched to  [flutter_file_dialog](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_dialog) plugin, It doesn't work on iOS, Same as file_picker plugin.

I doesn't log any error except `Warning: Attempt to present <UIDocumentPickerViewController: 0x12a5bdb70> on <BaseNavigationController: 0x104875800> whose view is not in the window hierarchy` on xcode logger.
I've tried different versions and different plugins they all not working.
The example app always works, But in my app doesn't seem to function at all.

Is there any solution for this?

My environment:

```
sdk: ">=3.1.0 < 4.0.0"
```

Simulator & physical device too.
Added permission first -> No effect, Same issue.